# WP_Query - multiple custom post types and sort by custom meta

Tags: wordpress, sorting, custom-post-type, meta

I'd like get results from two custom post types and sort them by custom meta (date of start events).

This code:

```
$warsztaty_q = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('kalendarium', 'warsztaty'),
    'order_by' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'data_start',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

Would be ok but first sorted is 'kalendarium' and then 'warsztaty' so in query results first sorted are posts from 'kalendarium' and next from 'warsztaty' not together.

I found this solution:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71576/combining-queries-with-different-arguments-per-post-type

But I can't get custom meta :(

Anyone can help me? :)

Comment: is 'data_start' shared from both post types?

Comment: Yes, 'data_start' is in both post types.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

use `orderby` instead of `order_by`

```
$warsztaty_q = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('kalendarium', 'warsztaty'),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'data_start',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

refer [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) for more details

Comment: Bro! You are my master! :D
Thank you very much. I saw order_by in many examples so I thought it is right way :)